# Как составить алгоритм комбинаторной задачи?

Tags: objective-c, c, c++, алгоритм

Уже второй день не могу составить алгоритм решения данной задачи.

+Даны три буквы - Б, С, К

+Сколько существует способов заполнить этими буквами N-количество клеток, при условии что:

- 1) Никакая из букв не может быть записана подряд;
- 2) Буква **С** может быть только между буквами **Б** и **К** (или **К** и **Б**).

К примеру при N=3 существует четыре способы:

> БКБ КБК БСК КСБ

Comment: @derkode интересно, что вообще в вашем понимании есть "динамическое программирование"

Comment: @DreamChild уверен что это http://informatics.mccme.ru/moodle/file.php/9/dyn_prof.pdf

Comment: Ну в данном случаи я подразумевая, что необходимо подобрать формулу из Комбинаторики. Сначала необходимо определить какая тут конфигурация - размещение или перестановка (я даже с этим не могу определиться из-за отсутствия опыта работы с комбинаторикой).

Comment: Хм, вы пишете, что

> Буква **С** может быть только между буквами **Б** и **К** (или **К** и **Б**)

и в то же время вариант **БКБ** у вас считается правильным. Вы уверены?

Comment: Да. К и Б могут лежать по середине.

Comment: @derkode: А, и правда, перепутал **К** и **С**.

Answer (score 5):

Всё просто.

Обозначим `a_i` количество способов, которыми можно правильно заполнить ряд из `i` клеток. Попробуем найти рекуррентное соотношение на `a_i`.

Как можно «собрать» строку длиной `i`? Вы начинаете с пустой строки, приписываете каждый раз либо один символ (**Б** или **К**), либо пару символов (**СК** или **СБ**). При этом на каждом шаге у вас правильная строка.

Итак, какой у нас последний шаг?

1. Вы приписываете к строке длины `i-1` один символ. Правильная строка заканчивается либо на **Б**, либо на **К**, поэтому чтобы получить правильную строку на этом шаге, вы приписываете «противоположный» символ: **К** или **Б**. Такой шаг вы можете провести, имея *любую* правильную строку длины `i-1`.
2. Вы приписываете к строке длины `i-2` два символа: **С** и символ, «противоположный» последнему символу в строке. Такой шаг вы можете провести, имея *любую* правильную строку длины `i-2`.

Строки, полученные при помощи шагов типа 1 и 2 не совпадают между собой (у вторых на предпоследнем месте **С**), а значит, мы получили все возможные варианты без повторений.

Отлично, теперь подсчитаем общее количество путей. Вы можете сделать шаг типа 1 начиная от `a_{i-1}` правильных слов, и шаг сам по себе однозначен. Вы можете сделать шаг типа 2 начиная от `a_{i-2}` правильных слов, и такой шаг тоже однозначен. Итого:

```
a_i = a_{i-1} + a_{i - 2}
```

Найдём начальные значения: легко видеть, что `a_1 = 2`, `a_2 = 2`.

Дальше легко. Вы можете применить любой из стандартных методов вычисления рекуррентных последовательностей. Например:

```
a = 2
a_prev = 2
repeat (n-2) times
    tmp = a
    a = a + aprev
    aprev = tmp
```

(который считает за `O(n)`). Или матричный, который считает за `O(log n)`. Или применить производящие функции и получить замкнутую формулу. Или заметить, что ваша последовательность почленно вдвое больше последовательности Фибоначчи.

---

Заметьте, что [[@Михаил М](/users/12913/%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%85%D0%B0%D0%B8%D0%BB-%D0%BC)](/users/12913/%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%85%D0%B0%D0%B8%D0%BB-%D0%BC) предлагает по существу ту же идею, я просто расписал по-другому.

---

Распишу решение с производящими функциями, может, кому-то пригодится. (Это очень мощная техника; за строгостью и теоретическим обоснованием лучше обращаться на маткод.)

Не нарушая рекуррентного соотношения, можно положить `a_0 = 0`. Рассмотрим формальный ряд:

```
G(x) = a_0 + a_1 x + a_2 x^2 + a_3 x^3 + ...       (*)
```

тогда

```
x G(x) =     a_0 x + a_1 x^2 + a_2 x^3 + ...       (**)
x^2 G(x) =           a_0 x^2 + a_1 x^3 + ...       (***)
```

отсюда вычитая `(**)` и `(***)` из `(*)`, имеем:

```
G(x) (1 - x - x^2) = a_0 + (a_1 - a_0)x = 2x
```

то есть

```
G(x) = 2x / (1 - x - x^2).
```

Разлагаем на [элементарные дроби](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=2x%2F%281+-+x+-+x^2%29):

```
G(x) = (2/sqrt(5)) [ (sqrt(5) - 1) / (sqrt(5) - 1 - 2x) -
                     (sqrt(5) + 1) / (sqrt(5) + 1 + 2x) ]
```

Разложим дроби в бесконечный ряд. Вспоминая ряд для [геометрической прогрессии](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=a+%2F+%28a+-+x%29):

```
a / (a - x) = 1 + x/a + x^2/a^2 + ...
```

тут же получаем (`P = sqrt(5) - 1`, `Q = sqrt(5) + 1`, y = 2x):

```
G(x) = (2/sqrt(5)) [ ( 1 + y/P + y^2/P^2 + y^3/P^3 + ... ) -
                     ( 1 - y/Q + y^2/Q^2 - y^3/Q^3 - ... ) ] =
```

(положим `p = (sqrt(5) - 1)/2`, `q = -(sqrt(5) + 1)/2`, продолжаем)

```
     = (2/sqrt(5)) [ ( 1 + x/p + x^2/p^2 + y^3/p^3 + ... ) -
                     ( 1 + x/q + x^2/q^2 + y^3/q^3 - ... ) ].
```

Собирая коэффициенты слева и справа при `x^i`, имеем

```
a_i = 2/sqrt(5) (1/p^i - 1/q^i).
```

Заметив, что `pq = -1`, получим окончательно в более приятном виде

```
a_i = 2/sqrt(5) [ ((sqrt(5) + 1)/2)^i - ((1 - sqrt(5))/2)^i ].
```

Comment: С рекурентным решением я путаюсь, как можно с помощью динамического программирования (с промежуточным сохранением результатов в массив)?

Comment: @derkode: Ну, если вы объясните, что такое «с помощью динамического программирования»...

Comment: С применением производящих функций.

Comment: Придётся Вам, @derkode, теперь делать два варианта :) , чтобы убедиться, что результаты совпадают.



Забавно, я не математик, поэтому для меня описание выше выглядит как 



"- объясните, как сделать цикл по массиву?


- <15 строк математических выкладок>" :)

Comment: @Михаил М: при помощи этих выкладок можно получить ответ в «замкнутом» виде, то есть, выражение, зависящее только от `i`, соответственно вычисления будут за `O(1)`. Хотя возможно это не то, что хотел ТС. Но он сам попросил решение с производящими функциями :-)

Comment: О, это круто! Стоит оформить как апдейт к ответу

Comment: @Михаил М: добавил, заодно довёл вычисления до конца.

Comment: Cпасибо! 


Объясните, пожалуйста, как из "вычитая (\*\*) и (\*\*\*) из (\*), имеем:
G(x) (1 - x - x^2) = a_0 + (a_1 - a_0)x = 2x"? Куда деваются a_0 * x^2 - a_1 * x^2 - a_2 * x^2 + a_0 * x^3 -...?

Comment: @Михаил М: ну у нас же `a_i = a_{i-1} + a_{i - 2}`, поэтому `a_2 - a_1 - a_0 = 0`, `a_3 - a_2 - a_1 = 0` и т. д. Остальные коэффициенты сокращаются.

---
Пожалуйста!

Comment: Да, действительно!

Answer (score 3):

Надо завести массив от 1 до нужного N и постепенно его заполнять. В i-й ячейке будет написано, сколько вариантов заполнения i клеток.

Собрать вариант длины P можно из ...Б + К..., ...К + Б..., либо ...Б/К + С + К/Б... При этом любой из фрагментов может иметь любую длину меньше P. Причём, никогда С не будет на концах строки/подстроки. Достаточно очевидно, что ровно половина вариантов длины i - кончается на Б, ровно половина - на K.

Таким образом, имеем внешний цикл от 2 до N по нашему массиву и внутренний цикл по длине левой части. Суммируем, перемножаем, записываем... Например, для правила ...Б + К... будет `V[i] += V[j] / 2 * V[i - j] / 2`

**Upd:**

```
V[0] = 0;
V[1] = 2;  // В одной клетке - либо Б, либо К
for (int i = 2; i <= N; i++)
{
  V[i] = 0;
  for (...)
  {
    V[i] += V[j] / 2 * V[i - j] / 2
```

Comment: Я не могу правильно задать исходные данные. К примеру, если N=4, то ведь необходимо указать сколько при этом в колекции Б, К и С. Узнать С можно, разделив на 3, а вот К и Б?